# Chapel sum reduce: unresolved call 'sum(eltType=type int(64))'

Tags: chapel

I'm experimenting with Chapel to solve a simple problem:

> Find the sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 (ProjectEuler001)

This is my code:

```
module Main {

    const topValue = 1000;
    var mostWanted : [0..#topValue] int;

    proc main() {

        forall (elem,i) in zip(mostWanted, 0..) {
            if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
                elem = i;
            }
        }

        var total = sum reduce mostWanted;
        writeln(total);
  }
}
```

Then I receive the message:

```
001.chpl:6: In function 'main':
001.chpl:14: error: unresolved call 'sum(eltType=type int(64))'
```

But if I change the word `sum` to `max`, it gives me the right answer:  999.

What am I missing? I can't understand why `max` work and `sum` doesn't.

Comment: The error message indicates that there is no built-in `sum`reducer, which contradicts this paper: http://chapel.cray.com/papers/BriefOverviewChapel.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the only reduce operator in the paper I was reading was `max`, I mistakenly assumed that all reduce operator were written like their description in the paper.

> Chapel provides a number of standard reduction and scan operators,
>   such as **sum, product, logical and bitwise operations, and max/min**
>   (with or without location information).
>   http://chapel.cray.com/papers/BriefOverviewChapel.pdf

Actually, the reduce operators are written like the normal operators. The correct code should be:

`var total = + reduce mostWanted;`

> Reduce is an operator that combines a set of values to produce a single value. Reduce is useful because in parallel computation it is
>   almost always necessary at some point to compare or combine results
>   produced by different threads. The syntax for reduce is:
>
> `var varName = reduce_operator reduce iterator_expression;`
>
> In the code
>   above, **valid reduce_operators are: +, *, &, |, ^, &&, ||, min, max,
>   minloc, and maxloc**. Furthermore, iterator_expression can be an
>   expression of any type that can be iterated over, provided the
>   reduction operator can be applied to the values yielded by the
>   iteration. For example, the bitwise-and operator can be applied to
>   arrays of boolean or integral types to compute the bitwise-and of all
>   the values.
>
> To sum up all the elements of an array A of size 10, you write: var
>   sum = + reduce A;
>
> http://faculty.knox.edu/dbunde/teaching/chapel/#Reduce